# Как забиндить RIchTextBox или хотя бы работать с ним через свойство

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу как то забиндить свойство к RichTextBox чтобы брать оттуда текст

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641774/6808809

Comment: Пытался реализовать, не получается, можете привести пример, если не сложно

Comment: Вот вы программист, или пытаетесь им стать, неужели вам нравятся пояснения по типу "не работает", "ошибка", "не запускается", "не получилось", "сломалось", и так далее...? Я думаю нет. Так почему вы другим пишете такое? Неужели думаете, что мы сидим рядом с вами и видим, что именно вы там делаете, жмете, пробуете, какие ошибки получаете? В ваших интересах дать нам как можно больше информации по любому вопросу, который у вас возникает, не в наших. Пример выше я вам привел, подробный и полноценный.

Comment: Текст в каком формате брать собираетесь? Просто текст `string`? Тогда на кой вам RTB, если для этого вполне сгодится `TextBox`?